# How can I get Laravel's LengthAwarePaginator to render in the current view?

Tags: php, pagination, laravel-5.8

My problem is that when I use Laravel (5.8) for pagination, if I try to actually use the paginator, when the new page is returned it's just a (correct) standalone html snippet. As far as I can tell the info is correct, but it's not being rendered 'in place'. It just comes out as minimally rendered html.

In the paginator in the view I have:

```
    $categoryLevel->links()
```

I also tried adding a path to the current view, but this didn't work:

```
    $categoryLevel->links('/manager/reports/order-data/sections/category') <-- this one brings back the index view but doesn't have any of the info from the index method in the controller
```

I know there's a lot of junk below, but does anyone see right off where the issue is? I could really use the help!

My routes:

```
Route::get('manager/reports/order-data', 'Manager\Report\OrderDataController@index')->middleware('auth');
Route::get('manager/reports/order-data/category/ajax', 'Manager\Report\OrderDataController@categoryLevelAjax')->middleware('auth');
Route::post('manager/reports/order-data/category/ajax', 'Manager\Report\OrderDataController@categoryLevelAjax')->middleware('auth');
```

in the controller:

```
    /**
     * returns Orders report index view
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $start = (new Carbon('first day of January 2020'))->toDateTimeString();
        $end = Carbon::today()->toDateTimeString();
        $manufacturerLevel = Orders::getOrderDataReport($start, $end)->get();
        $categoryLevel = NULL;
       return view($this->view . '.order-data.test', compact('manufacturerLevel', 'categoryLevel'));
    }

    /**
     * Returns our order data table ajax response
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function categoryLevelAjax(Request $request, $offset = 10)
    {
        $dates = request('mbatable.daterange');
        $mfr_id = $request->manufacturer_id;
        $start = (new Carbon('first day of January 2020'))->toDateTimeString();
        $end = Carbon::today()->toDateTimeString();

        if ($dates && isset($dates['start']) && isset($dates['end'])) {
            $start = date('Y-m-d', intval($dates['start']));
            $end   = date('Y-m-d', intval($dates['end']));
        }
        $sizeLevel = NULL;
        $categoryLevel = Orders::getOrderDataByCategory($start, $end, $mfr_id);

        return view($this->view . '.order-data.sections.category', compact('categoryLevel', 'sizeLevel'));

    }
```

In my index view w/ javascript:

```
<div class="page-content-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="card m-b-20">
                    <div>
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <h4 class="mt-0 header-title padd-left-15">Order Data Report</h4>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    @include('includes/mbatable/daterange-picker')
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="accordion">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-header row" id="headingOne" style="border-bottom: 2px solid black">
                                        <div class="col pt-3 ml-5">Expand/Collapse</div>
                                        <div class="col pt-3"><strong>Manufacturer</strong></div>
                                        <div class="col pt-3"><strong>Quantity Ordered</strong></div>
                                        <div class="col pt-3"><strong>Total Amount Ordered</strong></div>
                                    </div>
                                    @foreach($manufacturerLevel as $key => $mfr)
                                        <div id="collapseOne-{{$key}}-{{$mfr->manufacturer_id}}" class="collapse show"
                                             aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion" aria-expanded="true">
                                            <div class="pl-2">
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col">
                                                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                                                            <button onclick="updateManufacturer('mfr-{{$key}}-{{$mfr->manufacturer_id}}', {{$mfr->manufacturer_id}})"
                                                                    class="btn btn-link collapsed"
                                                                    data-toggle="collapse"
                                                                    data-target="#collapseTwo-{{$key}}-{{$mfr->manufacturer_id}}"
                                                                    aria-expanded="true"
                                                                    aria-controls="collapseTwo-{{$key}}-{{$mfr->manufacturer_id}}">
                                                                <span id="mfr-{{$key}}-{{$mfr->manufacturer_id}}" class="mdi mdi-plus"></span>
                                                            </button>
                                                        </h5>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col pt-3">{{$mfr->mfr_name}}</div>
                                                    <div class="col pt-3">{{$mfr->total_quantity}}</div>
                                                    <div class="col pt-3">
                                                        ${{ number_format($mfr->total, 2, ".", ",") }}</div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div id="collapseTwo-{{$key}}-{{$mfr->manufacturer_id}}"
                                                     class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo"
                                                     data-parent="#collapseOne-{{$key}}-{{$mfr->manufacturer_id}}" aria-expanded="false">
                                                    <div class="card-header row" id="headingTwo" style="border-bottom: 2px solid black">
                                                        <div class="col pt-3 ml-3">Expand/Collapse</div>
                                                        <div class="col pt-3"><strong>Category</strong></div>
                                                        <div class="col pt-3"><strong>Quantity Ordered</strong></div>
                                                        <div class="col pt-3"><strong>Total Amount Ordered</strong>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="pl-2">
                                                        <div id='mfr-{{$key}}-{{$mfr->manufacturer_id}}-response'>
                                                            @include('manager/reports/order-data/sections/category')
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    @endforeach
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- end col -->
            </div> <!-- end row -->
        </div><!-- container -->
    </div> <!-- Page content Wrapper -->
</div> 

function updateManufacturer(x, mfr_id) {
    var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
    var _mfr_id = mfr_id;
    var spn = $('#' + x);
    var response_element = x + '-response';
    if(spn.hasClass('mdi-plus')){
        spn.toggleClass('mdi-plus');
        spn.toggleClass('mdi-minus');

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            data: {_token: _token, manufacturer_id: _mfr_id},
            url: '/manager/reports/order-data/category/ajax',
            dataType: 'html',
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            success: function(response)
            {
                var element =  $('#' + response_element);
                element.append(response);
            }
        });
    } else {
        spn.toggleClass('mdi-plus');
        spn.toggleClass('mdi-minus');
    }

    return true;
};
```

In my category view (an include in the index):

```
@if($categoryLevel)
    @foreach($categoryLevel as $key => $cat)
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col ml-5">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <button onclick="updateCategory('{{$key}}-{{$cat->manufacturer_id}}', {{$cat->manufacturer_id}}, {{$cat->category_id}})"
                            class="btn btn-link"
                            data-toggle="collapse"
                            data-target="#collapseThree-{{$key}}-{{$cat->category_id}}"
                            aria-expanded="true"
                            aria-controls="collapseThree-{{$key}}-{{$cat->category_id}}">
                        <span id="cat-{{$key}}-{{$cat->manufacturer_id}}" class="mdi mdi-plus"></span>
                    </button>
                </h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col pt-3">{{$cat->category_name}}</div>
            <div class="col pt-3">{{$cat->total_quantity}}</div>
            <div class="col pt-3">${{number_format($cat->total, 2, ".", ",")}}</div>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree-{{$key}}-{{$cat->category_id}}"
             class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree"
             data-parent="#collapseTwo-{{$key}}-{{$cat->manufacturer_id}}" aria-expanded="false">
            <div class="card-header row" id="headingThree" style="border-bottom: 2px solid black">
                <div class="col pt-3 ml-3">Expand/Collapse</div>
                <div class="col pt-3"><strong>Size</strong></div>
                <div class="col pt-3"><strong>Quantity Ordered</strong></div>
                <div class="col pt-3"><strong>Total Amount Ordered</strong>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="pl-2">
                <div id='size-{{$key}}-{{$cat->manufacturer_id}}-response'>
                    @include('/manager/reports/order-data/sections/size')
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
    @if($categoryLevel->hasMorePages())
        {{ $categoryLevel->links() }}
    @endif
@endif
```

And the code that gets the actual LengthAwarePaginator:

```
public static function getOrderDataByCategory($start, $end, $mfr_id = NULL, $offset = 10){

    $currentPage = LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage();

    if ($currentPage >= 1)
        $skip = ($currentPage - 1) * $offset;
    else
        $skip = 0;

    $select = 'count(*) as record_count, mfr.id as manufacturer_id, mfr.`name` AS mfr_name, pc.id AS category_id, 
    pc.name AS category_name, SUM(orders.qty) AS total_quantity, SUM((orders.qty * orders.retail)) AS total';

    $query = Orders::join('manufacturers as mfr', 'mfr.id', '=', 'orders.manufacturer_id')
        ->join('transactions as t', 't.id', '=', 'orders.transaction_id')
        ->join('products as p', 'p.id', '=', 'orders.product_id')
        ->join('product_categories as pc', 'pc.id', '=', 'p.category_id')
        ->whereBetween('t.transaction_date', [$start, $end])
        ->selectRaw($select)
        ->groupBy('mfr_name', 'pc.name')
        ->orderBy('mfr_name', 'asc');

    if($mfr_id){
        $query = $query->where('orders.manufacturer_id', '=', $mfr_id);
    }

    $categoryLevel = $query
        ->skip($skip)
        ->take($offset)
        ->get()
        ->values();

    return new LengthAwarePaginator($categoryLevel, $categoryLevel->first()->record_count, $offset, $currentPage, [
        'path' => LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPath(),
        'offset' => $offset
    ]);
}
```